# How to use Checkbox ClickListener correctly?

Tags: android, checkbox

I want to show a Seekbar, when I check an Checkbox and the Seekbar shall disappear, when I uncheck the Checkbox.

But it only works for me, that the Seekbar appears by clicking the Checkbox but doesn't disappear, when I uncheck the Checkbox.

I tried it with a ClickListener:

> begrenzungsCheckBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.filebegrenzungCheckBox);
>       begrenzungsCheckBox.setOnClickListener(filebegrenzungsListenerCheckbox);

```
OnClickListener filebegrenzungsListenerCheckbox = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        TextView filebegrenzungAnzeige = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.filebegrenzungAnzeige);
        SeekBar filebegrenzungsSeekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.filebegrenzungSeekbar);

        filebegrenzungAnzeige.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        filebegrenzungsSeekbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }
};
```

and here is the corresponding xml layout file:

> ```
> <SeekBar
>     android:id="@+id/filebegrenzungSeekbar"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:visibility="invisible"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
> ```

How to use the ClickListener in order to have the possibility to check and uncheck the Checkbox or which alternatives are there to realise that?

Comment: For that use setOnCheckedChangeListener.

Answer (score 2):

OnClickListener fires for every click event. It doesn't care whether the checkbox gets checked or unchecked. Use an OnCheckedChangedListener instead:

```
*your checkbox*.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        TextView filebegrenzungAnzeige = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.filebegrenzungAnzeige);
        SeekBar filebegrenzungsSeekbar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.filebegrenzungSeekbar);
        filebegrenzungAnzeige.setVisibility(isChecked ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
        filebegrenzungsSeekbar.setVisibility(isChecked ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
if (chk1.isChecked()) {
  ShowSeekBar();
} else { 
  makeInvisibleSeekBar();
}
```